# how to get selector from jquery object?

Tags: jquery

codes:

```
   var jqueryObj=$("#readme");
   alert(jqueryObj.length); // result == 0
```

can i get "#readme" from jqueryObj ?
like:

```
   alert(jqueryObj.selector); //i want get "#readme"
```

BTW: i want to get selector,not element ID,  and  jqueryObj.length == 0.

Comment: Why would you do that? You have to select an element before you can act on it. So, `alert('jQueryObj')` must have been selected already.

Comment: Interesting. In both your question and your code, you're looking for something you already have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uhm... have you tried? http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Deleted 'half a page of incorrect code' due to endless discussion. Refer to decezes answer for complete solution ...

Comment: The jQuery object's `.length` attribute has absolutely nothing to do with how many times an element is allowed to appear on the page. Also, if it did match an element, even just one, `.length` is `1`.

Comment: Read carefully: I said an elements ID has to be unique!
But your right with the length ...

Comment: I never disputed that an id has to be unique, it just has nothing to do with the question or your explanation. Even with your correction, the rest is still nonsense. You **can** use `.selector` on the jQuery object, even if it contains more than one result.

Comment: Come on ... I never said that you can't use .selector. lazyanno asked 'can i get "#readme" from jqueryObj ?' (read: an ID!) and I explained how ... sorry that I overread the 'BTW' and tried to help with a detailed solution. Next time I'll just post some link to an API Doc and start moaning around, too ... :-)

Comment: Actually, you *did* say "here you can't use .selector". And I'm not moaning, I'm snootily pointing out an incorrectness. ;P Sorry if you feel that an (apparently) helpful 4 word answer is worse than half a page of incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ggggg').selector
```

is the correct way of getting the selector for the jQuery object.

This is what you had in your original post, have you tried it?